Obscure Behavior When Chaining Function Pointers and Recursion in C
I've stumbled upon some seriously head-scratching behavior in a C project, and I'm starting to wonder if I'm hitting some compiler- or language-specific limitation. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_t)(callback_t);

void recursive_func(callback_t next_call) {
    printf("Function iteration...\n");

    if (next_call) {
        next_call(next_call);  // Unbounded recursion
    }
}

int main() {
    void first_call(callback_t c) { recursive_func(c); } 
    void second_call(callback_t c) { recursive_func(c); }

    first_call(second_call);  // Start the chain
    return 0;
}


In theory, this should produce a neatly recursive chain of first_call -> second_call -> recursive_func, looping a few times with the "Function iteration..." message. However I am not.
Here is some outputs i got
Compiler A: Segfaults after a few iterations.
Compiler B: Works for a while, then output becomes garbled.
Compiler C: Runs surprisingly long, then suddenly halts.
Is this code invoking undefined behavior according to the C standard? It's the self-referential callback within recursive_func that makes me suspicious.
Could this be exceeding some compiler-specific limit on nested function calls involving pointers?
Are there more elegant or standard-compliant ways to achieve similar chained recursion with function pointers in C?
I'm less interested in workarounds for this specific example and more interested in understanding the fundamental limitations of C that might be exposed here.
Let me know if you've encountered anything similar or have insights into the depths of C's function pointer handling!

I don't think this should even compile, you can't define functions inside other functions. And if it were to compile, it clearly looks like an infinite loop. You call first_call(second_call), and it will call second_call(second_call), which calls second_call(second_call), and so on and so forth.

Welcome to SO. "However I am not." Well, would you mind telling us what happens instead? And yes, you will hit some limitations as you do not specify any situation where your recursion might end.

@Verpous: GCC has an extension of allowing function definitions inside functions. However, this code does not compile because, in, typedef void (*callback_t)(callback_t);, the scope in which callback_t may be used as the type being defined does not start until the end of the declarator, which is after the ) that closes the parameter list.

Is this the exact code you compiled and executed? Per the C standard, the scope of callback_t in typedef void (*callback_t)(callback_t); does not start until after the ) that closes the parameter list. If that is the exact code, which compiler did you use, which version, and with what switches? Re “Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing”: It is okay, even preferred, to provide a simplified version, but it must be a simplified version that reproduces the problem. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

“However I am not” is not an adequate description of the observed behavior.

It is bewildering why anybody votes up questions like this. Code that does not reproduce the problem (because it does not compile), no description of the observed behavior, no real interesting question.

Re “In theory, this should produce a neatly recursive chain of first_call -> second_call -> third_call -> recursive_func,”: What theory says third_call will be called when there is no reference at all to third_call anywhere in the program? It is nowhere passed as an argument, called directly, or otherwise used.

@Verpous Nice ly soptted, but no loop at all. Infinite recursion instead.

It's getting even more interesting: What would callback_t as parameter resolve to if that was possible at all? typedef void (*callback_t)(void (*)(callback_t)); – ouch, yet again its own definition. How often do you want to go on???

@Aconcagua, GCC 8 seems to be interpreting that parameter as an untyped name, not a type, which is somewhat reasonable given that the file-scope callback_t identifier is not in scope at that point.  C does not allow that, of course (it is a constraint violation), but that avoids the declaration being recursive.

You are telling first_call to call second_call, but you are passing second_call to itself with next_call(next_call), so second_call will call itself infinitely after that.
Incidentally, in the literature this technique is known as "continuation passing", you should find a lot of useful information if you search for this.

Thanks! I think this is the closest answer

The type definition typedef void (*callback_t)(callback_t); is not valid because the callback_t inside the parameter type list is undefined. There is no way to declare a function type that has a parameter that is a pointer to its own function type, or to declare a pointer to a function type that has a parmeter that is its own pointer to a function type.
The recursive declaration can be broken by defining another pointer to a function type that has an empty parameter list, and using type casts to convert the type of the parameter and/or the type of the function. For example:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_t)();
typedef void (*callbackback_t)(callback_t);

void recursive_func(callback_t next_call) {
    printf("Function iteration...\n");

    if (next_call) {
        ((callbackback_t)next_call)(next_call);  // Unbounded recursion
    }
}

void first_call(callback_t c) { recursive_func(c); } 
void second_call(callback_t c) { recursive_func(c); }

int main() {
    first_call((callback_t)second_call);  // Start the chain
    return 0;
}

Note that the execution of the function call first_call((callback_t)second_call); is infinitely recursive:
first_call((callback_t)second_call) =>
 recursive_func((callback_t)second_call) =>
  second_call((callback_t)second_call) =>
   recursive_func((callback_t)second_call) =>
    ...

It is likely to run out of call stack space eventually unless the compiler is smart enough to replace the infinite recursion with an infinite iteration.
